# Difference between (float)m/f and (float)(m/f)

Tags: java, c++, casting

```
int m = 10;
int f = 3;
float r = (float)m/f;    // gives 3.333333 as output
float r = (float)(m/f);  // gives 3.0 as output
```

Can anyone tell me how the parentheses are changing the answer because I am basically typecasting the integer value of `m/f` into float. What I don't understand is how the addition of brackets around `m/f` is changing the answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of `()`? What is associativity?

Comment: The parentheses changes the order of evaluation which all you really need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case:

```
(float)(m/f)
```

you are doing integer division first and then casting to float and therefore you lose the fraction. In the first case you cast `m` to float and therefore end up performing floating point division.

The cast operator has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in both C++ and Java but using parenthesis around the division forces it to be evaluated first.

In *C++* his behavior is due to the *usual arithmetic conversions* which is covered in the draft C++ standard section `5` *Expressions* paragraph *10* which says:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:

and includes the following bullet:

> — Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.

In *Java* this behavior is covered in the [JLS section 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)  which says:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:

and includes:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:

and includes:

> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.

and includes the following example:

```
int i    = 0;
float f  = 1.0f;

// First int*float is promoted to float*float, then
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is *what* gets converted to float. In the first case `m` gets converted to `float`, so the entire expression becomes floating point. In the second, you perform the expression (integer division) and then convert to `float`, at which point it's too late to save those precious significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

On the first example, `m` gets casted to float first then divided which gives you a floating-point number. The second example, the division is an int division so it will give you an int number that then gets transformed to a floating-point number.

Adding parentheses, change precedence of operators. Type casting is applied before division normally but using parentheses you tell compiler to divide before casting to float.

Answer (score 1):

`(float)m/f` divides `(float)m` by `f`. Since one of the operands is a float, the operator is floating-point division, and the answer is 3.333 etc.

`(float)(m/f)` calculates `(m/f)` and casts it to float. Since both operands are integer, the operation is integer division, and `m/f` is 3. Then 3 is casted to `float` to become 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations: Casting applies before division, and division between two integers always rounds (down) to the nearest integer in Java.

```
float r = (float)m/f;    // Is the same as ((float)m)/f, and because there's a
                         // float in the division, we keep everything a float.
float r = (float)(m/f);  // Is division between two integers, so we round down
                         // to the nearest integer before casting to a float.
```